# Self-injective ring but not semisimple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, injective-module

It is well-known that if $K$ is a field, then $K[x]/(f(x))$ is a self-injective ring for any polynomial $f(x)$ in $K[x]$. On the other hand, we know that a ring $R$ being semisimple is equivalent to the fact that every finitely generated $R$-module is quasi-injective.

My question is that could one replace "finitely generated" by "cyclic"?

The ring $R=\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2)$ is not semisimple since it is not von Neumann regular. If each cyclic $R$-module is quasi-injective, then the answer to my question is "No". But, the last sentence is not clear to me, and I thank to any person helping.

Comment: What exactly have you tried to do in order to solve (1), for example? Your point (2) is missing something, as it does not mean anything as it is now.

Comment: Your description of the ideals of $R$ is not correct.

Comment: This is not correct: since $\mathbb Q$ has no non-zero proper ideals, that would mean that $I$ must be $\mathbb Q$, so that $R$ has no proper non-zero ideals, and that conclusion is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to be sure, the question in the OP appears to be

> If all cyclic $R$ modules are quasi-injective, does that imply $R$ is semisimple?

And then you are working on a counterexample to disprove the statement.

The point is that the cyclic $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2)$ modules are all quotients of $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2)$, and there are very few (only three) of them. Let $R:=\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2)$.

$R/R$ is trivially quasi-injective.

If $I$ is the ideal generated by $(x+(x^2))$ in $R$, then $R/I$ is simple, so it's also  quasi-injective.

The only question is if $R$ is quasi-injective as a module over itself. Any module homomorphism from $\{0\}$ or $R$ trivially extends to $R$, so the only question is if any module homomorphism from $I$ to $R$ can be extended to be from $R$ to $R$.

Can you see the fairly obvious method of how to extend such maps? Ensure your choice makes a well-defined mapping.

Alternatively, if you already know $R$ is self-injective, you can immediately explain that $R$ is already quasi-injective.

This establishes that all cyclic modules of $R$ are quasi-injective. But $R$ is clearly not semisimple since commutative semisimple rings do not have nonzero nilpotent elements ($R$ has the nilpotent element $x+(x^2)$.)

---

If you really wanted to build a toy, you could replace $\Bbb Q$ with the field of two elements. Then $R$ has only four elements, so it would be very easy to check all maps from $I$ to $R$!

Comment: Thanks for answering. For inferring that $R$ is QI could we say, first,that for any module $N$, $R_R⊕N$ is QI if and only if $R$ and $N$ are both injective $R$-modules? For then, by setting $N=0$ we deduce that $R$ is QI iff it is self-injective ($R$-module).

Comment: @karparvar That sounds overcomplicated to me. From the definition of quasi-injectivity, and knowledge of Baer's criterion, you can already see that quasi-injectivity and injectivity are equivalent for rings. The stuff with $N$ seems roundabout. If you are already willing to assume the fact that $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2)$ is injective, you can just freely conclude $R$ is quasi-injective.